# how to play a sound for 5 seconds

Tags: android

i want to play a sound for 5 seconds but the code which i am using is playing the sound infinitely.

My code is

```
final MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
AssetFileDescriptor afd = this.getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.hangout_ringtone);
player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
afd.close();
player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
player.setLooping(true);
player.prepare();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to remove this line from your code

```
player.setLooping(true);
```

Comment: @swati If the problem is solved then please click the Accept checkbox :)

Answer (score 2):

Use a Runnable with a delay to stop your audio.

```
postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //Code to stop your sound
    }
}, 5000);
```

Comment: I don't know the context where you're posted code is, but you may call postDelayed on any View for example, or any Handler.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new handler to post a delay for when to stop.

```
            mMediaPlayer.start();
            // wait 5 sec... then stop the player.
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mMediaPlayer.stop();
                }
            }, 5000);//millisec.
```